# False proof of convergent harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\displaystyle\{x^{(k)}\}_{k = 1}^\infty = \sum_{i = 1}^k\frac{1}{i}$. We know that $\frac{1}{k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, so there exists a $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $m > M, \frac{1}{m} < \frac{\epsilon}{k}$. We then split the sum into $\sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{1}{i} + \sum_{i = m + 1}^k\frac{1}{i} < \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{1}{i} + {k}\frac{\epsilon}{k}= \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{1}{i} + \epsilon$.
The first term is finite, so it converges, and so does the second one.
What did I do wrong here to get this?

Comment: The first expression $\sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{1}{i} + \sum_{i = m + 1}^k\frac{1}{i}$ usually only has meaning when $k > m$, but if $\epsilon < 1$ then it's impossible to also have $1/m < \epsilon/k$.  Otherwise, if you have some convention to interpret $\sum_{i=m+1}^k$ when $k < m$, you should keep it in mind and interpret the following inequalities carefully.

Comment: You used the dummy index in your founding inequalities. Big nono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is your upper summation limit, then the $M$ you find will be $>k$ for $\epsilon<1$. This makes the lower summation limit greater than the upper limit, i.e. the only way to make sense out of $\sum_{i=m+1}^k\frac 1i$ is to interprete it as $-\sum_{i=k+1}^{m}\frac1i$, which totally breaks the argument. Moreover, the first summand is finite for each $m$ (which suddenly becomes $n$??), but not bounded.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. The $n$ was a typo.